# Importing ng-redux just returns a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngredux

I have problems importing ng-redux into my JS client app:

```
import ngRedux from 'ng-redux';
import needle from 'needle'; // just for debugging

console.log(`Testing: `, {ngRedux, needle});
```

Output from console is:

```
Testing: {
    needle: {version: "1.6.0", defaults: ƒ, head: ƒ, get: ƒ, post: ƒ, …},
    ngRedux: "ngRedux"
}
```

So `needle` works but `ngRedux` just returns a string, why?

The folder `node_modules/ng-redux` looks just fine.

Comment: The string must be module name, you just need to add it to module's dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns string, because only thing you need to do is set module as app's dependency, like this:

```
import ngRedux from 'ng-redux';
angular.module('app', [ngRedux]); // Creating "app" module
```

If you need to get module, you can write this:

```
angular.module(ngRedux); // Getting existing "ngRedux" module
```

Comment: Thanks! My challenge is that I'm not running browserify on the entire client app, so I can't use `import` in the `angular.module` code. Can I do something similar to `angular.module('myApp', [window.myBrowserifyBundle.ngRedux]);`?